# OneNote 2010 - deleting sections that were automatically imported

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

Why, when I tried to save then reopen a OneNote 2010 notebook, are the sections I typed gone and blank sections titled after my document folders that it won't let me delete left behind? How can I delete those sections and retrieve the work I did?

Comment: do you have any screen shots that may help us? :) also, what were you doing when you saved your notebook?